# What does readlink systemcall do?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I can't understand the operation of the "**readlink**" systemcall in Linux.

Can anyone explain about it with simple example on it?

Comment: Note that the [`readlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html) call does not null-terminate the data that it returns, but it does return the length so that you can add the null terminator easily enough.  It is crucial to pay attention to the return value, therefore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a *symbolic link*, e.g.

```
$ ls -l /vmlinuz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 2009-08-03 08:59 /vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.28-15-generic
```

then `readlink` syscall will get you the symlink target (`boot/vmlinuz-2.6.28-15-generic`), just like `readlink` command:

```
$ readlink /vmlinuz
boot/vmlinuz-2.6.28-15-generic
```